# Regex to find segment of string searching from end

Tags: regex

I'm in Java and have a string that will always be in this format:

```
;<a href="#" onClick="return CCL(this,'#461610734')" cs="c6"><b>gerg(1314)</b><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;(KC)</a><br>
```

This number 461610734 will change and may be any length.. I'd like to pick that number out and use it. As you can see the number is next to a `'` (the first one working backwards) and a hash `#` (again, the first one working backwards).

I can find the numbers after the hash by using `([^\#]+$)` and I can find up to the last `'` by using `([^\']+$)` (but this would be on the wrong side of the `'`...)

I'm lost... Anyone know how to join these two together and nudge the `'` along one to the left to just get the numbers?

Comment: Would something like `(?<='#)\d+` as a Java string `(?<='#)\\d+` help you? Using a lookbehind.

Comment: This one works perfectly! Thanks! my idea was so far away! hah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I believe that you could simply extract "the digits that immediately follow a `#`".

You could then use the following regex: `(?<=#)\d+`.

---

On the other hand, if you really want to specify that your digits are following a `#` and followed by a `'`, you could (should?) make use of the `look-around`s.
The following regex should be what you're looking for:

```
(?<=#)\d+(?=')
```

You can see it live by clicking this [link](http://regex101.com/r/xS4xH7).

Comment: this would work perfectly (i should have mentioned that there were a few numbers missing from the beginning of the string which i didnt inclide in the string example... hence the request for backwards.) Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = ";<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"return CCL(this,'#461610734')\" cs=\"c6\"><b>gerg(1314)</b><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;(KC)</a><br>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("onClick=\"return CCL\\(this,'#([0-9]+)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // Prints 461610734
}
```